# Where Can I Get a Durable cat 6 Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, cable

I am in the unfortunate position of needing a wired network connection for my laptop. I also need to attach and remove the cable several times a day. A 10 foot cat 6 cable works great, and I have bought many of them. But I would like to find a cable with a more durable connector. After a few months of use, the little plastic locking latch/clip breaks off. I know these connectors are not designed for heavy use, but is anyone aware of cables with more durable connectors? Or even just a source for more durable connectors (I can assemble my own cables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first used "rugged ethernet connector" for search terms, but changed to "industrial ethernet connector" after seeing those terms in the search results.

[image: rugged ethernet connector]

The above photo is courtesy of [TE Connectivity](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/intersection/industrial-rj45/industrialrj45-ip20.html), but other links appeared from the search, which may be better suited or less expensive, or easier to find.

This TE model certainly appears rugged and durable. No broken plastic clips when they are made of metal!

Comment: It all comes down to using the right search terms. Never thought of "industrial". Thanks!!!

Comment: @JohnAnderson, Beware that tugging the cable might break the computer's ethernet jack (or the computer!). These durable connectors are usually paired with an equally durable RJ-45 jack on industrial equipment. The plastic clips on RJ-45 plugs may be weak *by design* to prevent a worse sort of failure when the cable is pulled too hard.